# Python - Dictionary with Lists and tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

End Goal to create the following Dictionary

```
DictFinal = {'peach': [7,33], 'berries': [33,47], 'grapes': [47,98], 'apple': [98,200]}
```

snippets of code

```
FinalEndofline = 200
List1 = ["apple","peach","grapes","berries"]
List2 = [98,7,47,33]
```

Step1 : To create a dictionary using key value.List1 is the key and List2 is value.

```
professions_dict = dict(zip(List1, List2))
print professions_dict

Output - {'apple': 98, 'peach': 7, 'grapes': 47, 'berries': 33}
```

Step 2 : Sort the dictionary based on value

```
sorted_x = sorted(professions_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print sorted_x

Output - {'peach': 7, 'berries': 33, 'grapes': 47, 'apple': 98}
```

Step 3 : Now how do I achieve

```
DictFinal = {'peach': [7,33], 'berries': [33,47], 'grapes': [47,98], 'apple': [98,200]}
```

The Dictfinal is again a key value, but a value having the list with first value and second value and goes on and it appends the finalendofline variable to last value list

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or why you want to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> List1 = ["apple","peach","grapes","berries"]
>>> List2 = [98,7,47,33]
>>> List1 = [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(List2, List1))]
>>> List2.sort()
>>> List2.append(200)
>>> DictFinal = dict((key, List2[i:i+2]) for i, key in enumerate(List1))
>>> DictFinal
{'berries': [33, 47], 'grapes': [47, 98], 'peach': [7, 33], 'apple': [98, 200]}
```

That's fairly straightforward.  This is probably a bit more efficient, though -- only requires one `sort()`.  If efficiency really matters, you could also use itertools to do the slice on the second zip (and, of course, with Python 2, you would want to use izip instead of zip).

```
>>> List1 = ["apple","peach","grapes","berries"]
>>> List2 = [98,7,47,33]
>>> zipped = sorted(zip(List2, List1)) + [(200,)]
>>> FinalDict = dict((x[1], [x[0], y[0]]) for x, y in zip(zipped, zipped[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
List2 = ["""Blah""",FinalEndofLine]
unsorted = dict(zip(List1,[[List2[i],List2[i+1]] for i in range(len(l2) - 1)]))
DictFinal = sorted(unsorted.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][0])
```

This seemed to work for me, if I understand your problem fully. `List2` just needs that `FinalEndofLine` at the end.